# Finding elements with XPath in Delphi

Tags: delphi, xpath

I am trying to find an element in an XML document in Delphi. I have this code, but it always says 0 elements in the log:

```
function TForm1.KannaSidu: Boolean;
var
  Doc: IXMLDOMDocument; 
  List: IXMLDomNodeList;
begin
  try
    Doc := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDomDocument;
    Doc.async:=False;
    Doc.load(Filename);
  except
    LogTx('Error on page');
  end;
  List:=Doc.selectNodes('/html/head');
  LogTx(IntToStr(List.length)+' elements');
  Result:=False;
end;
```

So how do I make XPath work?

Comment: What does the XML file look like?

Comment: @Gunnar: Bruce is right. Without seeing the XML you're using, it's impossible to provide the answer to your question. Without that info, your XPath expression looks perfect; of course, it may be 100% wrong for the XML you actually have.

Comment: The XML contains much data. It is an XHTML document. I can see from the XML parse errors that it is malformed in several places.

Answer (score 3):

In the example code I find online for the `selectNodes` method, it is preceded by code that sets the document's [`SelectionNamespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756048.aspx) property via `setProperty`. Some even set `SelectionLanguage`, too.

```
Doc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
Doc.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces',
  'xmlns:xsl=''http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform''');
```

Based on the element names you're searching for, I guess you're processing an HTML file. The basic HTML elements are in the [*http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml* namespace](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/), so try this:

```
Doc.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces',
  'xmlns:x=''http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml''');
List := Doc.selectNodes('/x:html/x:head');
```

See also:

[selectNodes does not give node list when xmlns is used](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/a2370212-d88d-4af8-a126-be453313ebee) on Microsoft's forum.

Comment: I don't think it is the reason here. Moreover setProperty only exists in IXMLDOMDocument2, not in IXMLDOMDocument.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to load a plain html file as xml, it would probably have multiple reasons to fail and choke on things like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

You have to test that it actually loads correctly before doing anything else:

```
  if not Doc.load(filename) then
    raise Exception.Create('XML Loading error:' + Trim(Doc.parseError.reason));
```

It will give you the specific reason for the failure like this one:

```
XML Loading error:End tag 'head' does not match the start tag 'link'.
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me, parseError caught an ID10T error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

`IXMLDOMDocument.Load()` does not raise an exception if something goes wrong with your file or with its content. Try the following to be sure there is nothing bad with it:

```
...
Doc.load(Filename);
if Doc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
  ShowMessage('Error : ' + + Doc.parseError.reason) 
else
  ShowMessage('No problem so far !');
...
```

I suck at XPath but maybe if `html` is your root node you don't need to include it in your query string, so try the following :

```
List:=Doc.selectNodes('//html/head');
```

or

```
List:=Doc.selectNodes('//head');
```