# How does it work XPath in delphi?

Tags: delphi, xpath

this is my xml file (content.xml):

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

that is my code in Delphi (XE5):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 doc: IXMLDocument;
 Sel: IDOMNodeSelect;
 List : IDOMNodeList;
 query: String;
 begin
   content := TFile.ReadAllText('C:\temp\content.xml');
   doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
   doc.LoadFromXML(content);
   doc.Active := True;
   query := '//descendant::html';
   Sel := doc.DOMDocument as IDomNodeSelect;
   List := Sel.selectNodes(query);
  // List.length is 0 !!!!
end;
```

The question why List is empty, shoud contain four elements: HTML, head, body, h1(that's "html" tag and all its children. According to http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp XPath syntax I've tried that options:

```
//html/* 
/html
/html/*
```

none of them Works for me so at this point I do not know if the query is ok or my code fails in another point.

Comment: Surely a duplicate therefore I strongly doubt that this won't be downvoted/closed. In the meantime take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383919/xpath-and-txmldocument).

Comment: [Finding elements with XPath in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406138/finding-elements-with-xpath-in-delphi)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I've tried right now, but not working, first I am using IDomNode and I need to get IDOMNodeList and also I would like that the query Works because follows XPath Syntax from W3S.

Comment: Hi bummi, I am using this http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/enabling-xpath-selectnode-selectnodes-methods-in-vcl-and-firemonkey-apps/ and as you can see my example is almost the same, but still not working.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to use MSXML with Delphi so you need to make sure you first call

```
doc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath')
```

then set

```
doc.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"')
```

and finally you need to use that prefix `xhtml` anywhere you want to qualify elements e.g.

```
doc.selectNodes('//xhtml:h1')
```

selects all `h1` elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not using MSXML. "doc" variable belongs to Xml.XMLIntf library.

Comment: @user3779155: FYI - XMLIntf is a wrapper for MSXML under windows

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest NOT using `TFile.ReadAllText()` in this situation. Let `TXMLDocument` load the file directly, then you don't have to deal with any encoding issues.

You can get rid of `doc.LoadFromXML()` and set the `doc.FileName` property instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc: TXMLDocument;
  ...
begin
  doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
  try
    doc.FileName := 'C:\temp\content.xml';
    doc.Active := True;
    ...
  finally
    doc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or you can or replace `TXMLDocument` with the `LoadXMLDocument()` function, which takes a filename as input:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc: IXMLDocument;
  ...
begin
  doc := LoadXMLDocument('C:\temp\content.xml');
  ...
end;
```

Either way, then you can deal with the XPath query as Martin Honnen suggested.

Comment: Remy why are you using TXMLDocument in the first example? Should also be IXMLDocument?

Comment: Ideally, yes. But I was keeping with the OP's example, and it is valid to use `TXMLDocument` directly as long as it has an Owner assigned.

Comment: Ah, missed that detail :)

Answer (score -1):

After hours the error was really simple, the "content" variable has to be AnsiString NOT String. XPath was right, but not the variable.

That's wrong

```
var
 content: String;// WRONG should be content: AnsiString;
 begin
  content := TFile.ReadAllText('C:\temp\content.xml');
  doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
  doc.LoadFromXML(content);
  doc.Active := True;

 end;
```

I was looking at the wrong place: Query Variable and XPath Syntax.

Comment: `List.length is 0 !!!!` as before, I don't see how this can be the answer, the main problem, the namespace is not handled. Even the declaration of content was not shown in the question.

Comment: I would suggest NOT using `TFile.ReadAllText()` in this situation. Let `TXMLDocument` load the file directly. Get rid of `doc.LoadFromXML()` and set the `doc.FileName` property instead, or replace the `TXMLDocument` component with the `LoadXMLDocument()` function, which takes a filename as input.